# Inconsistent display of > 1k views on "new questions with activity"

Tags: bug

Normally when a question has more than 1k views it shows as 1k, 2k etc. rather than 1234 views.

This isn't the case for questions appearing (after ajax/etc) above the "new questions with activity" message, in that case is shows the exact number.

Comment: Screenshot. or it ***did not happen***

Comment: What page are you seeing this on?

Comment: On the meta.stackoverflow.com homepage, the "Community-led deletionism: a protocol for sanity" question was edited by CasperOne (no SS sorry)

Comment: I added a screenshot for you :-P

Comment: This is also happening on the favorites page (and many other meta.so pages) **not** confined to the main homepage.

Comment: That screenshot shows it correct though!, the question(s) appeared above the "(2) new questions with activity" message. The question highlighted had it's views as 2083 (or whatever it was)..

Comment: I saw it has 2038 views. When you hover over the 2 you can see that as a tooltip.

Comment: @Oded: Right, but when it was ajaxed in above the "new posts with activity" message, it showed as the actual number (2038), rather than being truncated as 2k. Is this done on the client (maybe my browser had a funny 5 mins?).

Comment: hmmmmm I don't know...

Comment: I think I understand now - when the page returns from polling (or using web sockets or whatever), instead of the 2k display logic, you see the full value? Is that the case?

Comment: @Oded: That's exactly it. Sorry for the confusion! :)